# RhinoMocks VerifyAllExpectations fails for multiple Expects on stubbed method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

Dear RhinoMocks users out there. I am a newbie to RhinoMocks and have a problem wrapping my head around something. I need to test two methods in a class, on of them calls the other multiple times. I already tested the one called multiple times separately, the setup is somewhat complex so the idea for testing the other method was to stub the method that has been tested already. Here is a minimal example:

```
     public class TestedClass
     {
         public virtual void DoSthOnce(List<int> listParam)
         {
             foreach (var param in listParam)
                DoSthMultipleTimes(param);
         }

         public virtual void DoSthMultipleTimes(int intParam)
         {
             Console.WriteLine("param: " + intParam);
         }
    }
```

I.e. `DoSthMultipleTimes()` is already tested. The following test code works and verifies that the `DoSthMultipletimes()`-Method was called for each element of the list that was provided as parameter to `DoSthOnce()`.

```
    var paramList = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
    var mock = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<TestedClass>();
    mock.Stub(m => m.DoSthMultipleTimes(Arg<int>.Is.Anything))
        .WhenCalled(mi =>
        {
            // Only for debug; this method is empty in the actual test code.
            Console.WriteLine("Stub called with " + mi.Arguments[0]);
        });

     mock.DoSthOnce(paramList);

     // This will not throw an exception
     foreach (var param in paramList)
         mock.AssertWasCalled(m => m.DoSthMultipleTimes(param));
```

The output is as expected:

```
    Stub called with 1
    Stub called with 2
    Stub called with 3
    Stub called with 4
    Stub called with 5
    Stub called with 6
    Stub called with 7
    Stub called with 8
    Stub called with 9
    Stub called with 10
```

However, the following fails throwing an exception although it should be the same thing as above, at least from my understanding:

```
    var paramList = Enumerable.Range(1, 10).ToList();
    var mock = MockRepository.GeneratePartialMock<TestedClass>();
    mock.Stub(/*same as above*/).WhenCalled(/*same as above*/);
    foreach (var param in paramList)
        mock.Expect(m => m.DoSthMultipleTimes(param));

    mock.DoSthOnce(paramList);
    mock.VerifyAllExpectations();
```

The console output is identical, but an ExpectationViolationException is thrown by `VerifyAllExpectations()`. Additional information is:

```
    TestedClass.DoSthMultipleTimes(1); Expected #1, Actual #0.
    TestedClass.DoSthMultipleTimes(2); Expected #1, Actual #0.
    ...
    TestedClass.DoSthMultipleTimes(10); Expected #1, Actual #0.
```

The parameters are correct, but what exactly is the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing because of your stub itself.

This piece of code would register the various expectations that you want:

```
foreach (var param in paramList)
    mock.Expect(m => m.DoSthMultipleTimes(param));
```

This would set the Expectation that DoSthMultipleTimes(1), DoSthMultipleTimes(2), etc are being called.

However your Mock.Stub code would override / stubbing the implementation itself. This resulted that Rhino would execute this override/method (and not calling the original DoSthMultipleTimes method of the original class). As such, when VerifyAllExpectation being called, none of the method in original class was called.

You could verify the above by removing the following:

```
mock.Stub(m => m.DoSthMultipleTimes(Arg<int>.Is.Anything))
    .WhenCalled(mi =>
    {
        // Only for debug; this method is empty in the actual test code.
        Console.WriteLine("Stub called with " + mi.Arguments[0]);
    });
```

Since you are using PartialMock, if you are not implementing the stub, it would call the original method. And supposedly, it would now successfully pass all the expectation.

(NB: beware when using PartialMock as it would run the original method if not being stubbed (ie: database call, etc)).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I expected as much. As I've tried to explain, the setup to have the original non-stubbed method run is somewhat complex and would result in quite a lot of duplicate test code. That's why I wanted to stub the method in the first place. Does that mean that I can't use Expect in this particular case?

Comment: I believe you wouldn't be able to use Expect in this particular case. Btw, if you had tested using the AssertWasCalled -- what more do you want to gain by using the Expect?

Comment: Nothing to gain, just trying to understand. Thanks!